# oEmbed Field in SilverStripe 3

Tags: silverstripe, oembed

I'm trying to figure out if there's a possibility to use SilverStripe's oEmbed functionality without the WYSIWYG editor. Sadly I just could find [this](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/class-Oembed.html) in the SS docs.

So is there a way to enable that functionality for example for a TextField?

Comment: What exactly are you wanting it to do with a text field? Display a preview inline or switch the URL out for some data that has been entered? If you posted a Youtube link into a text field, it can't embed it because it is still just a text field. The best it could do is display some HTML but it wouldn't know if your data type supports that.

Comment: You should be able to enter the link to the source and than get the embedded content in the template

Comment: OK, essentially a simple text field where you could paste in a Youtube/Vimeo/Facebook/Twitter/Instagram link which when entered into the template like `$MyOEmbedLink` would correctly render the specified content in the correct way? (eg. display a video, show a status, show an image?) This lets me narrow down how to best answer you question.

Comment: Yes exactly like that.

Comment: Awesome, I will see if I can chase up an answer for you then. :) Off the top of my head, vanilla SS won't do it but it should be possible with a module (possibly a module already exists).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This module has a special form field for oembeds... will do the trick https://github.com/sheadawson/silverstripe-linkable

Comment: I think that's exactly what I need. I'll test it later that day.